# replacement for InputTracking.GetLocalPosition in unity

Tags: unity-game-engine

when using

`OVRPose headPose;
headPose.position = InputTracking.GetLocalPosition(Node.Head);`

in a function, I get the following warning warning

Warning CS0618  'InputTracking.GetLocalPosition(XRNode)' is obsolete: 'This API has been marked as obsolete in code, and is no longer in use. Please use InputTracking.GetNodeStates and look for the XRNodeState with the corresponding XRNode type instead.'  Oculus.VR   E:\unityProjectsLocal\Voolkan VR\Assets\Oculus\VR\Scripts\OVRInput.cs   460 Active

the script is long so i'll focus the question in those few lines

```
using Node = UnityEngine.XR.XRNode;
using NodeState = UnityEngine.XR.XRNodeState;
....
public static OVRPose ToTrackingSpacePose(this Transform transform, Camera camera)
{
    OVRPose headPose;

    headPose.position = InputTracking.GetLocalPosition(Node.Head);
    headPose.orientation = InputTracking.GetLocalRotation(Node.Head);

    var ret = headPose * transform.ToHeadSpacePose(camera);

    return ret;
}
```

how can I use the `InputTracking.GetNodeStates` to replace it?
how can i get from `List<NodeState> nodes;
        InputTracking.GetNodeStates(nodes);` to `Node.Head`?

Comment: Maybe [this](https://forum.unity.com/threads/updating-from-getlocalrotation-to-getnodestates.695527/) serves as a startpoint?

Answer (score 2):

Simply checkout [`GetNodeStates`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/XR.InputTracking.GetNodeStates.html) which fills a list of [`XRNodeState`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/XR.XRNodeState.html). to get a specific one I would use [Linq `FirstOrDefault`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.firstordefault)

```c#
using UnityEngine.XR;
using System.Linq;

...

private Vector3 headPosition;
private Quaternion headRotation;
private List<XRNodeState> nodeStates = new List<XRNodeState>();

...

InputTracking.GetNodeStates(nodeStates);

var headState = nodeStates.FirstOrDefault(node => node.nodeType == XRNode.Head);
// This is basically a shortcut for using something like
//XRNodeState headState = null;
//foreach(var node in nodeStates)
//{
//    if(node.nodeType == XRNode.Head)
//    {
//        headState = node;
//        break;
//    }
//}

if(headState != null)
{
    headState.TryGetPosition(out headPosition); 
    headState.TryGetRotation(out headRotation);
}
```